# Is it possible to pass a component as an argument in Flex/AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, mxml

I know that ActionScript3 allows functions to be passed as arguments to be other [functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148982/passing-a-function-to-another-function-in-actionscript-3). Is it possible for an MXML component to be passed as an argument for a function? If so how?

For instance, I would like to do something like this:

```
private function getGlobalXY(comp:UIComponent):Point{
    return comp.localToGlobal(new Point(0, 0)));
}
```

But I get an error: "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: UIComponent."

This is as part of a Flex Project. I am using Flex 4.7.

Comment: Yes you can pass anything as argument, this error has nothing to do with passing arguments.

Comment: That error indicates that you don't have the Flex framework available in your project.  Did you create an "Actionscript project" in Flash Builder?

Comment: @Brian It is a Flex project, not Actionscript project (just added as edit). Could that be causing the error?

Comment: You *do* have the import statement in your code, right? (sorry if this is asking a too-obvious question)

Comment: Another thought:  Check any libraries that you're importing.  I think it can cause problems if you're importing e.g. a Flex 3 .swc in a Flex 4 project.

Comment: @Brian :/ "import mx.core.UIComponent;" was missing. Thanks. Add it as an answer and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change UIComponent on DisplayObject:

```
private function getGlobalXY(comp:DisplayObject):Point {
    return comp.localToGlobal(new Point(0, 0)));
}
```

Also, don't forget to import the classes you want to use.